# Use loadedlibs structure lua 5.2.3

Tags: lua, embedded, lua-5.2

How can I use loadedlibs structure from linit.c in lua 5.2.3. I add my new library in this struture and I want to call the functions of my library from a lua script.

Comment: The questions you have been asking are all related. You need to give us more information on what you're trying to achieve and what you have done so far. Show us some code.

Comment: I make a new library with 4 functions. I add this in the struture luaL_Reg of linit.c. I add the part for my new library in lualib.h too. And so I want to call this function from a lua script. In the script I do a call of the function of my new library. And it don't work. Maybe I need to put more code for linking the lua script and my new library ? This is the question

Comment: @Subas Edit the question put the information there instead.